# PHP Date to Javascript Date becomes Time Difference?

Tags: php, javascript, datetime, datatable, timezone

I'm using JS `DataTable` and the `Date Column` must be sortable. But it can't sort as **JS assume the Dates imported as the Strings**. (It doesn't sort in actual chronological order. Just in string order)

Then as i googled, i start realized that JS can only sort JS Dates. Means, i need to convert PHP Date into JS Dates.

But i can't get it properly yet. What i did is:

```
<script>
    var jsDate = new Date(
                        <?php echo $phpDate_y; ?>,
                        <?php echo $phpDate_m; ?>,
                        <?php echo $phpDate_d; ?>
                    ); // $phpDate will be "2012-04-30";
</script>
```

But on rendering, the jsDate is transformed as:

```
Thu Oct 03 1935 00:00:00 GMT+0730 (MALST)
```

**FAR DIFFERENT!!

And, my timezone location is `Singapore`.

Is there any other proper way pls :(**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a full date string to the JS Date object to construct it so try passing $phpDate in one of the ISO date formats into the Date constructor instead of splitting it the way you're doing it.

```
// $phpDate = '2012-08-17 12:29:06'
var jsDate = new Date("<?php echo $phpDate; ?>");
```

Comment: Woah `JS Date` can accept `PHP Date` directly? I haven't known it before. Yes it works in that way as my way was wrong. Thanks!! ;)

Comment: It works, and additionally to `Re-format` the date in appearance, i found following JS Date Formatter. Thanks again! :D .. http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');**

first line in your PHP scripts.

[php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)